# Accessing type <T> passed in from class (public class TheClass<T>) in the method

Tags: c#, generics

For instance I have a class:

```
 public class GenericController<T> : ApiController where T : BaseContext 
 {
    public string Get(int id) 
        {
            try
            {
                var obj = dataRepository.Get<T>(id);

                responseMessage.SetGetSuccess(obj);
            }
                catch (Exception e)
            {
                responseMessage.SetGetUnsuccess(e);
            }
            return responseMessage.ToJsonString();
        }
 }
```

Is this possible?
T is not recognized in the method

The error message is this:

```
Error   16  'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'AppCore.NHibernateBases.DataRepositories.Interfaces.IDataRepository.Get<T>(int)' C:\Users\SeanPC\Google Drive\SideProject\DataAPI\DataAPI\Controllers\GenericController.cs   44  27  DataAPI
```

Comment: How is `repo` defined?  Does the class for which `repo` is an instance   have a generic method called `Get`?  What is the exact error message?  (btw:  Your `GetSomething` method is invalid in that it does not return a value.

Comment: Can you post exact error message?

Comment: Ill just post what i actually have

Comment: It looks like there is a constraint `where T : new()` in the repository class that your controller needs to honor (by replicating it).

Comment: dataRepository and responseMessage is injected into the constructor, but thats not my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is recognized within your method. Problem is different. It does not fit into generic constraint set on `Get` method you're trying to call.

> 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method '`AppCore.NHibernateBases.DataRepositories.Interfaces.IDataRepository.Get<T>(int)`'

To make that work, you have to add the same constraint on your class:

```
public class GenericController<T> : ApiController where T : BaseContext, new()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all, you are missing a constraint. `Get<T>` method needs a type which is `not abstract` and has a parameterless constructor.

In order to be able to pass `T` type to `Get`, you must change your constraint:

```
 public class GenericController<T> : ApiController where T : BaseContext, new()
 {
    public string Get(int id) 
    {
        try
        {
            var obj = dataRepository.Get<T>(id);

            responseMessage.SetGetSuccess(obj);
        }
            catch (Exception e)
        {
            responseMessage.SetGetUnsuccess(e);
        }
        return responseMessage.ToJsonString();
    }
 }
```